# How can I send e-mails via Gmail SMTP via OpenSSL (on Windows)?

Tags: networking, email, smtp, openssl

I know that the SMTP server requires TLS so I'm using OpenSSL (on Windows).

```
openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465 -crlf
```

Now, I know that I have to encode a string (basically `\x00myemail\x00password`) that has my account and password using base64. Things work pretty well:

```
AUTH PLAIN <encodedString>
235 2.7.0 Accepted
```

The problem is when I try to write my message:

```
MAIL FROM:<myemail>
250 2.1.0 OK qwertyzxcv.1 - gstmp
RCPT TO:<myemail>
RENEGOTIATING
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Inc, CN = Google Internet Authority
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
```

The truth is that I don't understand that error message. Do I have to generate some certificate? If so, how do I do it (again, on Windows)?

EDIT[0]: I finally solved the problem. You HAVE to write the command `rcpt` in lowercase because `R` makes OpenSSL to renegotiate. But now, I have a new problem. It seems that the SMTP server can't recognize de `DATA` command:

```
DATA
502 5.5.1 Unrecognized command qwertyzxcv.1 -gsmtp
```

Comment: Please post the solution as an actual answer instead of an update to your question. Be detailed and specific.

Comment: @Ramhound I tried to do that but it says that I didn't have enough karma and I had to wait like 8 hours or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I finally solved my two problems:.

1. The first problem was about the `RENEGOTIATING` thing. The solution is to write the commands (or at least the ones that start with `R`) in lowercase. [OpenSSL interprets a uppercase `R` as a command for renegotiation of the TLS](http://tumbleweed.org.za/2007/07/17/sclients-r-feature).
2. The second problem was that the server "didn't recognize the DATA command". This problem is at the very beginning:

   `openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465 -crlf`

All tutorials on the internet say that you should use the `-crlf` option and it's true, **for Linux**. If you're using Windows do NOT use that option. That option is, [according to the documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/s_client.html):

> this option translated a line feed from the terminal into CR+LF as required by some servers.

I thought that even though Windows uses CR+LF, OpenSSL forced the newline to be LF just to have consistency with the unix implementation. I was wrong. In fact, right now, I don't know what the `-crlf` option does *on Windows*. Maybe it translates CR+LF into LF? That would be pretty weird though, given the name of the option.

Comment: +1 Almost spot on.. BUT, re your point 2, what did it for me was doing -crlf and that was on windows.  I don't think it makes a difference what your OS is. It'd a question of what the server supports as your quote of documentation suggests. Even in Windows, a command - any command - a unix port of a command  e.g. something in gnuwin32  could use just LF, it could produce a file with LF rather than CRLF. No command/program has to use the OS's favorite of CRLF or LF.   So my guess is openssl s_client by default uses LF, and can be made to use CRLF.

Comment: so I think that line means that the -crlf option translates an LF from the openssl s_client program (and that LF will be given whether it's a windows port or *nix port), it translates it into a CRLF.  smtp.gmail.com requires CRLF. And i'm on Windows with a cygwin openssl port, connecting to smtp.gmail.com with openssl s_client and it only worked with -crlf. But I got the idea of doing that, from your answer. So now it accepts the DATA command. Spot on with the R too I found that moments before reading your answer, but that's a very important point you make.